# Get working days,hours,minutes between two dates in sql server

Tags: sql-server

**Input** 
startdate - 2020-05-01 10:05:07.000 
enddate -    2020-05-18 12:08:07.000

**Expected Output** 
12D:02H:03M

I need output like aobve which is having hours minutes with days

Iam having query from which iam getting only working days ,below is the query

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(dd, receive_date, GETDATE()) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, receive_date, GETDATE()) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, receive_date) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) from email
```

other query i have like this

```
select dbo.fn_WorkDays(receive_date, getdate() ) from email
```

Comment: I suggest getting a Calendar table, and storing the details of the working days and working hours (if needed) in there. Then this becomes quite trivial.

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service. Someone wrote a similar function - so use that as a basis to write your own function to return the desired value. And note that there is no datetime-related datatype you can use for the return value - be careful what you wish. Also, as current events have demonstrated, be careful how you determine "work day".

Comment: Are you guaranteeing that start and end never fall on a weekend?

Comment: `datediff(second, st, en) % 86400 / 3600` gets you hours. Minutes follows a similar pattern.

Comment: no,there is no guarantee that start date and end date never fall on a weekend

Answer (score 0):

You could break it down to total seconds and then pull out the parts you need.

**EDIT**

Ok, I see now that you need to use only weekdays. I am certain there is a more eloquent way to do this, but this should give you a start.  I would imagine using a calendar table might make it easier.

I made it so that if one of the start or end dates started on a weekend the calculation should still be correct.

Consider the following:

```
DECLARE @startdate as datetime =  '2020-05-01 10:05:07.000'
DECLARE @enddate as datetime = '2020-05-18 12:08:07.000'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  @startDate stDate, DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @startdate)+1, 0)) EndDate 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,1,stDate) < DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @enddate)) 
            THEN  DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(day,1,stDate) )) 
            ELSE @enddate 
        END,
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,1,stDate) < DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @enddate)) 
            THEN  DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(day,1,stDate))+1, 0))
            ELSE @enddate 
        END      EndDate

    FROM CTE
        WHERE DATEADD(day,1,stDate) <=  @enddate
)
,
ctSeconds as 
(

    SELECT COUNT(*) DayCount,MIN(stDate) stDate, MAX(EndDate) EndDate
    from CTE
    WHERE DATENAME(dw,stDate) NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
)

SELECT 

  FORMAT(DayCount, '00') + 'D:'
    + FORMAT ( (TotalSeconds % 86400) / 3600,'00') + 'H:' 
    + FORMAT ( (TotalSeconds % 3600) / 60, '00') + 'M' AS SPAN
FROM
(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,stDate, EndDate) TotalSeconds, DayCount from ctSeconds  
) x
```

RESULT

```
SPAN
12D:02H:03M
```

Comment: Hi JMabee, Thanks ,But I need only working days .something like 12D:02H;03S.Because between these two dates i have 3 weekends so need to subtract 6 days

Answer (score 0):

Check below query, It will help you

```
declare @startDate as datetime =  '2020-05-02 15:05:06.000'
        ,@endDate as datetime = '2020-05-18 12:08:07.000'

-- Minutes calculation START
declare @startRemainingMin int=datediff(SECOND,cast('1900-01-01' as time),cast(@startDate as time))
        ,@endRemainingMin int=datediff(SECOND,cast('1900-01-01' as time),cast(@endDate as time))
        ,@diffMin int
set @diffMin = @endRemainingMin-@startRemainingmin

-- Uncount if @endDate is sunday or saturday 
if(datename(DW,@endDate)='Sunday' or datename(DW,@endDate)='Saturday')
begin
    select @diffMin=-1*@startRemainingmin
end

-- Uncount if @startDate is sunday or saturday 
if(datename(DW,@startDate)='Sunday' or datename(DW,@startDate)='Saturday')
begin
    select @diffMin=@endRemainingMin
end
--Minutes calculation END

if(@diffMin<0)
begin
select @diffMin=86400+@diffMin
end

;with cteAllDate as(
select  @startDate as dt
    union all 
    select  
        dt+1
        from cteAllDate where dateadd(day,1,dt)<=@endDate
)
select cast(count(1)-sum(iif((datename(DW,dt)='Sunday' or datename(DW,dt)='Saturday'),1,0 )) as varchar(5)) + 'D:'
    + format ((@diffMin/3600),'00') + 'H:' 
    + format ( (@diffMin%3600/60), '00') + 'M:'
    + format ( (@diffMin%60), '00') + 'S' as result
from cteAllDate
```

**Output:**

```
result
10D:12H:08M:07S
```